# Using GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

With this query I got 2 columns of distinct values

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Transport.ID, Transport.Address 
FROM  
    Cars 
LEFT JOIN 
    Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom=Transport.ID 
ORDER BY 
    address
```

Now I need get one more column with sum:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Active='True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

But I get error if I do queries like

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Transport.ID, Transport.Address, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    Cars 
LEFT JOIN 
    Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom = Transport.ID 
ORDER BY 
    address
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Transport.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT 
    Transport.ID, Transport.Address, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    Cars 
LEFT JOIN 
    Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom = Transport.ID 
ORDER BY 
    address
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

```
SELECT 
    Transport.ID, Transport.Address, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    Cars 
LEFT JOIN 
    Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom = Transport.ID 
GROUP BY 
    ID
ORDER BY 
    address
```

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Ambiguous column name 'ID'.

```
SELECT 
    Transport.ID, Transport.Address, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    Cars 
LEFT JOIN 
    Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom = Transport.ID 
GROUP BY 
    Transport.ID
ORDER BY 
    address
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Transport.address' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How to get the syntax right?

Comment: You need to add `Transport.Address` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the error messages are clear, no ?

```
SELECT Transport.ID, Transport.Address, SUM(CASE WHEN Active='True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Cars 
LEFT JOIN Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom=Transport.ID 
--add all the fields from select clause which are not in an aggregation function
GROUP BY Transport.ID, Transport.Address 
ORDER BY address
```